# Can someone help me to produce this flow diagram in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

[image]

What I have done so far is nowhere near what I want:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}



\begin{document}
%Flow diagram Node Definitions
\tikzstyle{prof} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2cm,     minimum height=0.5cm,text centered,text width=8em, draw=black, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=15em, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [->, >=latex', shorten >=1pt, thick]
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=2cm,minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=2em, align=center]
\tikzstyle{cfr} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered,text width=15em, draw=black, fill=blue!40]
\tikzstyle{cbr} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text width=15em,text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!40]
\tikzstyle{hyb} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=1cm,text width=25em, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]


\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]


\node (bt) [cfr] {Phase 7};
\node (pp) [cbr, right of=bt, xshift=8.5cm] {Phase 1};
\node (newuser) [cfr, below of=bt,yshift=-2.5cm, xshift=-3cm] {Phase 2};
\node (olduser) [cbr, below of=pp,yshift=-2.5cm, xshift=2cm] {Phase 3};
\node (dm) [cbr, below of=bt, yshift=-7cm] {Phase 4};
\node (dmo) [cbr, below of=pp, yshift=-7cm] {Phase 5};
\node (ver) [cloud, below of=bt, yshift=-2.5cm, xshift=5cm] {Phase 6};

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Process Flow}
\label{pic:flow}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

Comment: Why have you filled them with blue if you want no fill? And why have you put an ellipse in the middle? And why do you define styles you never use?

Comment: I just re-used stuff from another flow process I drew in the past. That one was easier to produce because the joins to the nodes were straight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really doubt you produced that code trying to draw that picture, as it makes no sense to create a bunch of styles you never use with a deprecated syntax and colours you don't want. (So I wonder if the code is really from some unacknowledged source.)

There are packages for flowcharts, so you should probably investigate those.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,arrows.meta,positioning,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    node distance=2cm,
    >=Latex,
    cbr/.style={text centered, draw=black, minimum height=1cm, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, text width=15em, },
  ]
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=c]
    \draw (-.5,-.75) coordinate (a) [out=-30, in=120] to (.5,-.75) |- (-.5,.75) coordinate [midway] (b) -- cycle ;
    \clip  (a) |- (b) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(-2,0) |- cycle ;
    \begin{scope}[shift=(135:.25)]
      \draw (-.5,-.75) coordinate (a1) [out=-30, in=120] to (.5,-.75) |- (-.5,.75) coordinate [midway] (b1) -- cycle ;
    \end{scope}
    \clip  (a1) |- (b1) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(-2,0) |- cycle ;
    \begin{scope}[shift=(135:.5)]
      \draw (-.5,-.75) coordinate (a2) [out=-30, in=120] to (.5,-.75) |- (-.5,.75) coordinate [midway] (b2) -- cycle ;
    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
  \foreach \i [count=\j] in {60,120,...,360}
  {
    \node (p\j) [cbr] at (\i:7) {Phase \j};
    \draw [<->] (p\j) -- (c);
  }
  \foreach \i/\j [remember=\i as \ilast (initially 6) ] in {1,...,6}
  {
    \pgfmathor{\i==1}{\i==4}\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1\draw  [<->, densely dotted] (p\ilast) |- (p\i);
    \else\pgfmathor{\i==2}{\i==5}\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1\draw  [<->, densely dotted] (p\ilast) -- (p\i);
    \else\draw [<->, densely dotted] (p\ilast) -| (p\i);
    \fi\fi
  }
  \node (w) [right=of p6, double arrow, draw, text width=20mm, text centered] {Arrow};
  \node [right=of w, draw, cylinder, shape border rotate=90,  anchor=center, minimum width=15mm, minimum height=30mm] {Drum};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: flow]

Comment: Thanks for this. You are right, I just re-customised the code from my previous Thesis which was a bit easier because the arrows were straight. What I want now is a bit complicated. I can always add the fancy colours.